# How do I compile libffi for iOS & macOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, libffi

I'm trying to use [libffi](https://github.com/atgreen/libffi) in one of my projects, but I can't seem to compile for iOS (or macOS, for that matter). Here is one of the various errors I've encountered while building for the iOS Simulator:

```
bash: src/arm/gentramp.sh: No such file or directory
```

---

**Update 1:** Since the question remains unanswered, I've decided to open an [issue](https://github.com/libffi/libffi/issues/249) at the official repository as well.

**Update 2:** Question has been answered and the issue has been closed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generate-darwin-source-and-headers.py and the libffi.xcodeproj need to be updated to include all currently relevant source files.

The gentramp.sh script is not needed anymore and the current upstream xcodeproj is not up to date either with compilation settings and to be included source files for 64-bit on iOS. A patched fork can be found at https://github.com/ksjogo/libffi

Answer (score 2):

If you check the repository you will see that the file you require was deleted in [this commit](https://github.com/libffi/libffi/commit/a4b785ea695e929b91d64e1e8b514411ae8bafe8#diff-9287509a21d8dcbd5ce7985cbdc5aaf4). You can find the last version of this file [here](https://github.com/libffi/libffi/blob/c129bea82a25c9b0f3af3bf48c35c55257092f87/src/arm/gentramp.sh).

Answer (score 1):

1. `sh autogen.sh`
2. `python generate-darwin-source-and-headers.py --only-ios`
3. open `libffi.xcodeproj`
4. select scheme `libffi-iOS` and device `Generic iOS Device`
5. click "Product - Build"

   If success, you would see a "Product/libffi.a" in the side bar, you can right click it to get the lib in the finder.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are following the installing libffi instructions released on the TBD or git project: https://github.com/libffi/libffi

**Here some of the main Highlights:**

First you must configure the distribution for your particular
system. **Go to the directory you wish to build libffi in and run the
"configure" program found in the root directory of the libffi source
distribution.**

If you're building libffi directly from version control, configure won't
exist yet; run `./autogen.sh` first.

You may want to tell configure where to install the libffi library and
header files. To do that, use the `--prefix` configure switch.  Libffi
will install under `/usr/local` by default.

If you want to enable extra run-time debugging checks use the the
`--enable-debug` configure switch. **This is useful when your program dies
mysteriously while using libffi.**

Another useful configure switch is `--enable-purify-safety`. Using this
will add some extra code which will suppress certain warnings when you
are using Purify with libffi. **Only use this switch when using 
Purify, as it will slow down the library**.

For iOS builds, the '`libffi.xcodeproj`' Xcode project is available.

Configure has many other options. Use "`configure --help`" to see them all.

Once configure has finished, type "`make`". **Note that you must be using
GNU make.**  You can ftp GNU make from `ftp.gnu.org:/pub/gnu/make` .

To ensure that libffi is working as advertised, type "`make check`".
This will require that you have `DejaGNU` installed.

To install the library and header files, type "`make install`".

Alternatively, try merging one of the following git projects to your project in order to include the missing files. *Please make sure the files are not outdated before merging.*

**1** https://github.com/pandamonia/libffi-iOS

**2** https://github.com/influitive/libffi-iOS

**3** https://github.com/landonf/libffi-ios

Comment: This didn't work. I installed `dejagnu` via Homebrew and followed all your instructions; however I am still getting excessive cryptic errors. Xcode still complains that `gentramp.sh` is missing.

Comment: Try having a look to this repository, it has all configuration files in it: https://github.com/pandamonia/libffi-iOS

Comment: That particular fork is extremely outdated.